# Is it possible to edit a SQL Server maintenance T-SQL query without creating a new one? 

Tags: sql-server-2005, maintenance-plan

Need to edit a maintenance plan backup cleanup job.

It can't find any place to edit the job through a Query editor.

How can this be done without disabling the job and creating your own job?

tia.

Answer (score 3):

Given the right permissions, you should be able to go into your Object Explorer, find the maintenance plan in question, and *Modify* it:

[image]

and on the maintenance plan diagram, you should be able to just double-click on the `Execute T-SQL Statement Task` box to edit the T-SQL statement:

[image]